# Calculating Expected Value from Permutation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, permutations, combinations

> Two 2-digit numbers are formed by randomly selecting digits, without
> replacement, from the digits 1,2,...,9. What is the expected value of
> the product of the two numbers?

I figured that there are 72 two-digit numbers that you can make from 1,2,3...9 without replacement. However, calculating the expected value of the product of two of these numbers seems very tedious. I believe we can multiply the probability $\frac{1}{72}*product + \frac{1}{71}*product$ for every single combination but it seems very inefficient. How do we generalize it?

There is a similar question linked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3167702/calculating-expected-value-of-product-of-two-numbers), however, even after referencing it, I am unable to figure out the solution.

Comment: The rules are not clear.  Can a digit repeat between the two numbers?  That is, is $12, 23$ a valid pair (I understand that $11,22$ is not a valid pair, right?)

Comment: Regardless of that, linearity should work here $E[(10a+b)(10c+d)]=100E[ab]+10E[ad]+10E[bc]+E[cd]$ and all four of those expectations are the same.

Comment: The question states that the numbers are selected without replacement so no the digits cannot repeat. I believe (12, 23) would not be a valid pair either.

Comment: That does not alter the result, though you should edit your post for clarity.

Comment: @lulu:  I think it may affect the result: if you allow $(12,23)$ but not $(11,22)$ then $E[ad]$ is larger than it would be if you did not allow $(12,23)$.  I also suspect you may have intended to write $E[(10a+b)(10c+d)]=100E[ac]+10E[ad]+10E[bc]+E[bd]$

Comment: @Henry  Yes, you are right on the expansion (clearly) and also on the products.  When I say that all four expectations are the same, I certainly am assuming that no digit recurs in any term.

Answer (score 1):

@lulu provided the approach to make use of the common expectation of the product of two random digits (sampled at random from 1 to 9 without replacement) as

$$100E[ab]+10E[ad]+10E[bc]+E[cd]=E[ab](100+10+10+1)=121E[ab]$$

We have

$$E[ab]=\frac{\sum _{i=1}^8 \sum _{j=i+1}^9 i j}{\sum _{i=1}^8 \sum _{j=i+1}^9 1}=\frac{870}{36}=\frac{145}{6}$$

so the mean is $121E[ab]=121\cdot \frac{145}{6}=\frac{17545}{6}$.

Writing down all of the combinations by hand is certainly tedious but some software packages make it easy.  Here is the calculation of the mean using *Mathematica*:

```
(10 #[[1]] + #[[2]]) (10 #[[3]] + #[[4]]) & /@ Flatten[Permutations[#] & /@ 
  Subsets[Range[9], {4}], 1] // Mean
(* 17545/6 *)
```